# Function to dynamically extract values from multiple nested dictionary in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, nested, dynamic-programming

The problem statement is to write a function which will take a input dictionary object and return a list of all the values, even in case of multi-level nested dictionaries inside the input dictionary object.

Example of such a nested dictionary below:

```
{
    "f_name": "AKASH",
    "s_name": "NASH",
    "professional": {
        "designation": "DE",
        "company": "XYZ",
        "place_of_work": {
            "city": "BLR",
            "state": "KA",
            "country": "IN"
        }
    },
    "personal_address": {
        "city": "EKM",
        "state": "KL",
        "country": "IN"
    }
}
```

I did write the below code and I am able to extract the dictionary values, even incase of one nested dictionary by means of manual conditional if statement.

```
def dic_values(x):
    l =[]
    l1 = []
    if type(x) == dict:
        for i in x:
            if type(x[i]) != dict:
                l.append(x[i])
            elif type(x[i])== dict:
                y = x[i]
                for j in y:
                    l1.append(y[j])
    else:
        "Please input a dict object"
    l.extend(l1)
    return l
```

CASE 1:
On running the function with a dict object with one nested dictionary inside:

```
dic_values({"name":"AKASH","s_name":"NASH", "place":{"city":"BLR","state":"KA","country":"IN"}})
```

The Expected Output:

```
['AKASH', 'NASH', 'BLR', 'KA', 'IN']
```

CASE 2:
Like the below example, on having an input of multi-level nested dictionaries inside:

```
dic_values({"f_name":"AKASH","s_name":"NASH","professional":{"designation":"DE","company":"XYZ","place_of_work":{"city":"BLR","state":"KA","country":"IN"}}, "personal_address":{"city":"EKM","state":"KL","country":"IN"}})
```

The Output:

```
['AKASH','NASH','DE','XYZ', {'city': 'BLR', 'state': 'KA', 'country': 'IN'}, 'EKM', 'KL', 'IN']
```

Expected Output:

```
['AKASH','NASH','DE','XYZ', 'BLR', 'KA', 'IN', 'EKM', 'KL', 'IN']
```

QUESTION:
Say there were nested dictionaries present inside the input dictionary object. I would like to write a code, where the code dynamically checks for multi-level nested dictionary presence and executes. Like incase of CASE 2 Expected output.

Comment: Since this seems like a homework exercise, I'll not give an answer but suggest a solution path: note that you can make your function recursive. You loop through each value in the dictionary, appending them in the output list, unless you find a dictionary. In that case, you extend the list of the result of calling `dic_values` in the dictionary (this is your recursive call). That should handle any reasonable number of dictionary levels.

Comment: It really no harder to use a stack for this. Put the initial dict in a list. The while that list contains something, pop the next dict off. Loop through the values, append values that are dicts back to the stack, put values that are not in a second list of return values. When the stack is empty return the second list.

Comment: @Mark Since this is python (and we are on stack overflow), I think this solution is the better choice, since memory management for recursion is not pythons strength.

Comment: @nonDucor Appreciate the solution. Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
def all_dict_values(input_dict):
    result = []
    for value in input_dict.values():
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            result.extend(all_dict_values(value))
        else:
            result.append(value)
    return result
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Really helped in solving my problem, and in understanding a new function isinstamce()

Answer (score 0):

modify your existing code to recursively call the dic_values:

```
def dic_values(x):
    if not isinstance(x, dict):
        return [x]
    res = []
    for v in x.values():
        res.extend(dic_values(v))
    return [v for v in res if not isinstance(v, dict)]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It worked.    
Although the other answer was more understandable for a n00b like me. Appretiate your time.

Comment: your welcome appreciate if you upvote

Comment: I wish.    
I'm new to StackOverflow and I don't have any reputation yet. As soon as I get some, will do so for sure.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are interested in doing this in a non-recursive way. You can maintaining a stack of dicts as you go. So long as the stack has dicts in it there are more values to find:

```
def dic_values(d):
    assert isinstance(d, dict), "Please pass a dict"
    
    values = [] # this will hold the values
    stack = [d] # this should only contain dicts 
    
    while stack:
        next_d = stack.pop()
        for v in next_d.values():
            if isinstance(v, dict):
                stack.append(v) # put it back to process more
            else:
                values.append(v) # this a not dict, add it to the return list
    return values
        
        
dic_values({"f_name":"AKASH","s_name":"NASH","professional":{"designation":"DE","company":"XYZ","place_of_work":{"city":"BLR","state":"KA","country":"IN"}}, "personal_address":{"city":"EKM","state":"KL","country":"IN"}})
# ['AKASH', 'NASH', 'EKM', 'KL', 'IN', 'DE', 'XYZ', 'BLR', 'KA', 'IN']
```

Comment: Great help. Wonderfully explained. Thanks Mark :)